# Moving objects continuously - iOS - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am working on a game for iOS. I was wandering about some of the aspects as to how I could approach some of the development.

1) Does anyone know links to some great SpriteKit tutorials for iOS?

2) I am interested in moving a bunch of objects (UIImages representing characters) in a line continuously. Do you know how I could begin approaching this problem by using SpriteKit? How do you move the objects continuously? How do you make/delete the objects once they have left the screen?

If anyone could give me some tips or ideas as to what kind of tutorials or articles I can read to help me get some sort of basic understanding, that would be great.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Akaino's answer, the documentation and raywenderlich.com is very very thorough.

To answer your specific questions, the objects should probably be done using an `SKSpriteNode` object and not a `UIImage` as these are essentially the images of Sprite Kit.

To move an object in a straight line, I assume on one side of the screen and then off the other and then remove the object, use an SKAction that is performed when the object is created and then remove the object after.

```
SKSpriteNode* object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];
object.position = CGPointMake(x-coord,y-coord);
[self addChild: object];

SKAction* move = [SKAction moveToX:-50 duration: 1];
[object runAction: move completion:^{
  [node removeFromParent];
}];
```

Something like that to add a node, move it and then remove it.

Comment: Thank you Andy. Very helpful indeed :)

Answer (score -1):

You should go check the Sprite Kit Docs. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html. 
It's VERY helpful for beginners.
A very good site to a few sprite kit tutorials might be raywenderlich.com.

To your question:

Go check sprite kits update method.